# Prevent Header from Mashing with Text

Tags: fancyhdr, geometry, header

I am writing a document with standard margins set by the `fullpage` package. However, I am also trying to use `fancyhdr` to embed a header. Yet, when I print this, the header runs into the first line of text. How can I go about fixing this?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fullpage} %full page typesetting
\usepackage{setspace} %allows for non-singlespacing
\usepackage{graphicx} %graphics capabilities
\usepackage{latexsym} %extra symbols
\usepackage{rotating} %rotation for figures
\usepackage{longtable} %tables that fill more than a single page
\usepackage{hyperref} %hypertext links in the document
\usepackage{natbib} %better bibliographies
\usepackage{authblk} %author and affiliation in opening


%Put name and page number on subsequent pages
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\emph{Some Header}}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%\AtBeginDocument{\thispagestyle{empty}}

\newcommand\e{\emph}
\newcommand\tb{\textbf}
\newcommand\un{\underline}
\newcommand\txt{\texttt}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code from your question results in the following warning:

```
"Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (0.0pt): Make it at least 14.49998pt."
```

Following the advice given there, you can use `\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}` to prevent the header from overlapping with the first line of the following text.